# Are August monthly reputations points incorrect for some users?

Tags: discussion

I just took a look at the Users > Reputation > Monthly page and it looks messed up to me. Some users are showing their August monthly reputation as they should but others seem to be showing their quarterly reputation.

Maybe it's just my browser screwing up, but could one of the moderators look into this, and report back on whether or not it's a real problem?

#### Update

Repair seems to be in progress. I took another look and there are now fewer users showing inflated reputation for August. So I conclude it is/was a real problem.